# how can I alter my code to hide element on load?

Tags: javascript

I'm using this js code to show/hide elements on my site:

```
<script>
    function myFunction3() {
  var x = document.getElementById("dsec-three");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

Can anyone help me to set it so the elements are hidden on load and only show once activated?

Comment: Make it hidden by inline CSS or use JS to make it hidden on load.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `class` for `show/hide` elements same as :

```js
function showHide(){
  element = document.getElementById('element1');
  showHideEle(element)
}

function showHideMulti(){
  elements = document.getElementsByClassName('multi');
  Array.from(elements).forEach(ele => {
    showHideEle(ele)
  });
}

function showHideEle(ele){
  let isHide = ele.classList.contains('hide');
    if (isHide) {
      ele.classList.remove("hide");
    } else {
      ele.classList.add("hide");
    }
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<p class="hide" id="element1">para 1</p>
<button onclick="showHide()">Show/Hide</button>
<br />
<p class="hide multi">para 2</p>
<p class="hide multi">para 3</p>
<p class="hide multi">para 4</p>


<button onclick="showHideMulti()">Show/Hide Multi</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `myFunction3` already does the job of hiding and showing the relevant elements. All you need to do now is invoke the function when your document loads. You can do this by adding the following line inside your `<script>`:

```
document.addEventListener("load", myFunction3);
```

If you need the elements to stay hidden by default and show them after the document loads, you'll need to set the `display` property of those elements to `none` either via inline CSS.

Example (if your element is a `div`) :

```
  <div id="dsec-three" style="display:none">
  ...
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

what do you mean by activated?

if you mean that after the load of your page, you would need an event listener.

follow these steps:

1. set the initial display of your element to none.
2. create an event listener like load: and add your function there:

   document.addEventListerer('load', function(){
   myFunction3();
   })

the above code is telling the browser: 'when ever the page loads, call this function'

Comment: Code does not work, also improper formatting, spelling, and grammar. Read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener for proper event listeners, and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.